# How to select one file from list which comes after say file 'x' alphabetically

Tags: linux, unix, sed, find, ls

I am not so familiar with the linux scripting thing ...and had to do something weird.

I have a simple directory which has many folders in YYYYMMDD format... this is how it looks when I do a ls on the directory

[admin@xxx audit]$ ls

1145 20140827 20140828 20140829 20140830 20140831 20140901 20140902 20140903 20140904 20140905 20141020 20141021 20141022 20141023 20141024 20141025 20141026 20141027 20141028 20141029 20141030 20141031 nohup.out

Now what I have to do is copy one folder (in ascending order) to another directory.
I will save this folder name copied somewhere on my disc.

Now I need to copy again the folder which comes after the one which was copied previously and so on.

e.g. I copied first 1145 to the destination and saved it in last_copied_date.txt.
Now in next run I need to read last_copied_date.txt for this folder name and then since 20140827 comes next to 1145, copy it to the destination and replace the name in last_copied_date.txt with this newly copied folder name.

Again in third run 20140828 will be copied (remember 1145 and 20140827 still exists there on source directory) and last_copied_date.txt will be updated.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you say "folder" - do you mean "file" or "directory"? There are no folders in UNIX, just files and directories, and usually when someone says "folder" it's a Windows person who means directory but you specifically talk about directories in your question so it's not clear what you mean by "folder".

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume in this answer that your directory isn't modified between the iterations (i.e. none of your folder names will be added/removed/modified).

Let's first define a function that reads `last_copied_date.txt` and copies it to `destination`:

```
read_and_copy() { cp $(cat $1) destination; }
```

The initialization is simple, we want to do `ls` and only get the first line:

```
init(){ ls|head -n 1 >$1; }
```

The iteration step is a bit trickier, as we need to find the "next step after" the one right now and put it in `last_copied_date.txt`, this can be done easily through grep and tail.

```
next(){ ls|grep -A 1 $(cat $1)|tail -n 1 > last_copied_date.txt; }
```

So you can now assemble all of the above in a single function:

```
iteration() {
 if [[ -a $1 ]] ;
  then next $1;
  else init $1;
 fi
 read_and_copy $1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create below script on source path and do the same. What i understood from your example below script will do the same.

foldernamelist.txt should contain all the folder name you want to move.

You can use below commmand to create .txt file :

```
ls -d */ | sed -e "s/\///g" > foldernamelist.txt
```

Script :

```
for foldername in `cat foldernamelist.txt`
do
   echo $foldername  > last_copied_date.txt
   cp $foldername  /destination_path
done
```

Let me know if you find any issues.